# Optional query parameters are not working with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

Let's say we have the following database entry:

```
@Entity
data class Dog(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "breed") val breed: String?
)
```

As you can see, not every dog has breeds defined. Now we want to make a query to search all dogs based on their breed.

```
@Dao
interface DogDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE breed = :breed")
    fun getByBreed(breed: String?): List<Dog>
}
```

Sometimes we want to search for the dogs with the specific breed and sometimes we want to search for the dogs that don't have defined breed. The problem is that in the second case, the above query won't work. Why? When `breed` parameter from `getByBreed(breed:)` method is null, the Room will convert this query to something like this:

`SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE breed = NULL`

Unfortunately for SQLite querying for null values should look like this:

`SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE breed IS NULL`

The question is, how to define a query that accepts optional parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out the SQLite operators. Directly taken from this [link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

> The IS and IS NOT operators work like = and != except when one or both of the operands are NULL. In this case, if both operands are NULL, then the IS operator evaluates to 1 (true) and the IS NOT operator evaluates to 0 (false). If one operand is NULL and the other is not, then the IS operator evaluates to 0 (false) and the IS NOT operator is 1 (true). It is not possible for an IS or IS NOT expression to evaluate to NULL. Operators IS and IS NOT have the same precedence as =.

So what you should have and will be equivalent to what you have is:

```
@Dao
interface DogDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE breed IS :breed")
    fun getByBreed(breed: String?): List<Dog>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted.